# Jquery mention input : output data issue

Tags: jquery, comments, return, underscore.js

I'm working on my comment system for my website and I am not able to retrieve the value of the whole field.

I am using this script https://github.com/podio/jquery-mentions-input

```
return {
  init : function (options) {
    settings = options;

    initTextarea();
    initAutocomplete();
    initMentionsOverlay();
  },

  val : function (callback) {
    if (!_.isFunction(callback)) {
      return;
    }

    var value = mentionsCollection.length ? elmInputBox.data('messageText') : getInputBoxValue();
    callback.call(this, value);
  }
}
```

The function val is the one returning the value !

This is the code that i'm using to get the value. (it doesn't work)

```
 $('#commentInput').mentionsInput('val', function(comment){ var test = comment; });
     alert( test );
```

I would like to find a way to extract the value comment/test out of this function so it can be then sent to my database.

If I use this next code the alert box displays the good info.

```
('#commentInput').mentionsInput('val', function(comment) { alert(comment); });
```

I tried a few other manipulations to try and make it work, but I was always getting errors like [object Object] or [ HTMLDivElement]

I'm pretty sure it is something stupidly easy, but I cannot figure it out.

Hope someone could help me

Have a good day

Joris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joris,

`('#commentInput').mentionsInput('val', function(comment) { alert(comment); });` is the correct formulation. You just need to go a step further, as follows:

```
('#commentInput').mentionsInput('val', function(comment) {
    sendToDatabase(comment);
});
```

where `sendToDatabase` is a function that accepts a comment as its argument and uploads it (via ajax and a server script) to your database .... something like this:

```
function sendToDatabase(comment){
    $ajax({
        url: 'path/to/server/script',
        type: "GET", //or "POST"
        data: { "comment": comment },
        success: function(){
            //here display something to confirm that the upload was successful
        },
        error: function(){
            //here display something to indicate that the upload was not successful
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot, it is working perfectly. But I am still wondering why you can't just extract the value and put it in a variable ?
Thanks again @Beetroot-Beetroot and have a good day !

Comment: The function defined as the second parameter of `.mentionsInput()` is a callback function with a formal variable `comment`. The scope of 'comment' is confined to the callback function. Where you were trying to access `comment`, it was out of scope but also not yet set.